# How to add own "double click" plugin to Ultraedit

Tags: ultraedit

I want to add own "double click" plugin to Ultraedit editor which will on double click can show Hello window and a OK button.

Thanks in Advance..!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but UltraEdit v20.00.0.1054 itself has no interface to overload the double click event within document window by a customized action.